# Docker connection refused error Spring boot + MariaDB

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I am trying to connection MariaDB database using docker-compose, but I get the following error where I run containers using the command 'docker-compose up'

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name=net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy
spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url=jdbc:log4jdbc:mariadb://kipit_db:${DATABASE_PORT}/${DATABASE_NAME}?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=Asia/Seoul&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.hikari.username=${DATABASE_USER}
spring.datasource.hikari.password=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk

VOLUME /tmp

EXPOSE 8080

ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/kipit-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

ADD ${JAR_FILE} kipit.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/kipit.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
    kipit_db:
        image: mariadb:10.4
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    kipit:
        image: kipit
        depends_on:
            - kipit_db
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
            - 3308:3306
        environment:
            - DATABASE_USER=root
            - DATABASE_PASSWORD=root
            - DATABASE_NAME=test
            - DATABASE_PORT=3306
```

Set up a spring boot application that depends on a MariaDB called in docker-compose. After issuing docker-compose up I'm getting:

Error Log

```
Creating network "kipit_default" with the default driver
Creating kipit_kipit_db_1 ... done
Creating kipit_kipit_1    ... done
Attaching to kipit_kipit_db_1, kipit_kipit_1
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29 05:50:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.4.13+maria~bionic started.
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29 05:50:40+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29 05:50:40+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.4.13+maria~bionic started.
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29 05:50:40+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
kipit_1     |
kipit_1     |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
kipit_1     |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
kipit_1     | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
kipit_1     |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
kipit_1     |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
kipit_1     |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
kipit_1     |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)
kipit_1     |
kipit_1     | 2020-05-29 05:50:42 INFO [ main ] c.p.k.KipitApplication : Starting KipitApplication on 0fe8f9293838 with PID 1 (/kipit.jar started by root in /)
kipit_1     | 2020-05-29 05:50:42 INFO [ main ] c.p.k.KipitApplication : The following profiles are active: oauth
kipit_db_1  |
kipit_db_1  |
kipit_db_1  | PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MariaDB root USER !
kipit_db_1  | To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:
kipit_db_1  |
kipit_db_1  | '/usr/bin/mysqladmin' -u root password 'new-password'
kipit_db_1  | '/usr/bin/mysqladmin' -u root -h  password 'new-password'
kipit_db_1  |
kipit_db_1  | Alternatively you can run:
kipit_db_1  | '/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation'
kipit_db_1  |
kipit_db_1  | which will also give you the option of removing the test
kipit_db_1  | databases and anonymous user created by default.  This is
kipit_db_1  | strongly recommended for production servers.
kipit_db_1  |
kipit_db_1  | See the MariaDB Knowledgebase at http://mariadb.com/kb or the
kipit_db_1  | MySQL manual for more instructions.
kipit_db_1  |
kipit_db_1  | Please report any problems at http://mariadb.org/jira
kipit_db_1  |
kipit_db_1  | The latest information about MariaDB is available at http://mariadb.org/.
kipit_db_1  | You can find additional information about the MySQL part at:
kipit_db_1  | http://dev.mysql.com
kipit_db_1  | Consider joining MariaDB's strong and vibrant community:
kipit_db_1  | https://mariadb.org/get-involved/
kipit_db_1  |
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29 05:50:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29 05:50:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29 05:50:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Waiting for server startup
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.4.13-MariaDB-1:10.4.13+maria~bionic) starting as process 122 ...
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.13 started; log sequence number 60972; transaction id 21
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@3787a6d6386a' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Warning] 'user' entry '@3787a6d6386a' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@3787a6d6386a' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200529  5:50:44
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29  5:50:44 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
kipit_db_1  | Version: '10.4.13-MariaDB-1:10.4.13+maria~bionic'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  mariadb.org binary distribution
kipit_db_1  | 2020-05-29 05:50:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
kipit_1     | 2020-05-29 05:50:45 INFO [ main ] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
kipit_1     | 2020-05-29 05:50:45 INFO [ main ] o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol : Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
kipit_1     | 2020-05-29 05:50:45 INFO [ main ] o.a.c.c.StandardService : Starting service [Tomcat]
kipit_1     | 2020-05-29 05:50:45 INFO [ main ] o.a.c.c.StandardEngine : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
kipit_1     | 2020-05-29 05:50:45 INFO [ main ] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/] : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
kipit_1     | 2020-05-29 05:50:45 INFO [ main ] o.s.w.c.ContextLoader : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2707 ms
kipit_1     | 2020-05-29 05:50:45 INFO [ main ] c.z.h.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
kipit_1     | 2020-05-29 05:50:47 ERROR[ main ] c.z.h.p.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
kipit_1     | java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=kipit_db)(port=3306)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:kipit_db, port:3306. Conne
ction refused (Connection refused)
kipit_1     |   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:240)
kipit_1     |   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1192)
kipit_1     |   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:620)
kipit_1     |   at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:175)
kipit_1     |   at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:92)
kipit_1     |   at net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy.connect(DriverSpy.java:401)
kipit_1     |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
kipit_1     |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:354)
kipit_1     |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202)
kipit_1     |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
kipit_1     |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:554)
kipit_1     |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
kipit_1     |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
kipit_1     |   at com.project.kipit.config.DatabaseConfig.dataSource(DatabaseConfig.java:35)
kipit_1     |   at com.project.kipit.config.DatabaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$37c12367.CGLIB$dataSource$1(<generated>)
kipit_1     |   at com.project.kipit.config.DatabaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$37c12367$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3aa2a57.invoke(<generated>)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
kipit_1     |   at com.project.kipit.config.DatabaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$37c12367.dataSource(<generated>)
kipit_1     |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
kipit_1     |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
kipit_1     |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
kipit_1     |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1290)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1210)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1290)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1210)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1406)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1290)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1210)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:882)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
kipit_1     |   at com.project.kipit.KipitApplication.main(KipitApplication.java:20)
kipit_1     |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
kipit_1     |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
kipit_1     |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
kipit_1     |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
kipit_1     |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
kipit_1     | Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:kipit_db, port:3306. Connection refused (Connection refused)
kipit_1     |   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:240)
kipit_1     |   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.connException(ExceptionMapper.java:101)
kipit_1     |   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createSocket(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:468)
kipit_1     |   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:358)
kipit_1     |   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1187)
kipit_1     |   ... 89 common frames omitted
kipit_1     | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
kipit_1     |   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
kipit_1     |   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
kipit_1     |   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
kipit_1     |   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
kipit_1     |   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
kipit_1     |   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
kipit_1     |   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createSocket(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:463)
```

What i'am missing now? Thank you

Comment: exec dokcer container to see if you can connect mariadb with mysql client. btw, it seems even when you set root password on compose file, mariadb didnt create root user.

Comment: Are there more database startup messages after what you've shown in the output?  The "Temporary server started" line suggests to me that the database container has only gotten up to the point of getting itself ready to load the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` content, and isn't fully running yet.